# What lightbox/zoom library is here, I need the same?

Tags: jquery

My client wants lightbox or zoom library like [here](https://12storeez.com/catalog/trikotaz/womencollection/zilet-knit-115940) It's not magnific popup, I don't see it's classes

Is it slick lightbox? I see there is slick slider, but is there slick lightbox?

Maybe someone already used something similar and know what library or script to use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When clicking to big image I want to make it closer like there, on desctop, and by touch in mobile. What script or library can make it like that? Not photoswipe I'm sure - it makes fully black background around zoomed photo